# how to avoid repetition of item list in ansible

Tags: ansible

i have 2 hosts in my playbook, and i would like to put in a include my users items.

```
##remote servers
- hosts: test
  remote_user: ansible
  vars:
    users:
    - username: "user1"
      groups: "users,wheel"
    - username: "user2"
      groups: "users,wheel"

  tasks:
  - name: "Create user accounts"
    user:
      name: "{{ item.username }}"
      groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    with_items: "{{ users }}"

##local ansible server
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  vars:
    users:
    - username: "user1"
      groups: "users,wheel"
    - username: "user2"
      groups: "users,wheel"

  tasks:
  - name: "Create user accounts"
    user:
      name: "{{ item.username }}"
      groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Is there some syntax to avoid the repetition of the item-list?

I tried to put my items in a new file (users.yml)
I tried with this code/include :

```
  -hosts:test
   remote_user: ansible
   include_vars:
      file: users.yml
   tasks:
   -name: "create user accounts"
```

but i get an ERROR! conflicting action statements: include_vars, user

Is there some syntax to avoid the repetition of the item-list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a task.

```
 - hosts:test
   remote_user: ansible
   tasks:
    - name: Include vars
      include_vars:
        file: users.yml
    - name: "create user accounts"
      ...
      ...
```